# How to write Junit 5 Test Case when getting the response from AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, unit-testing, amazon-s3, junit5

```
public String getResponseFromS3(String applicationId, S3FileDirectoryEnum directory) {

    try {

        String key = getKey(applicationId, directory);
        GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = GetObjectRequest.builder()
                                                            .bucket(bucketName)
                                                            .key(key)
                                                            .build();


        ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse> s3ClientObject = s3Client.getObject(getObjectRequest);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s3ClientObject));

        return bufferedReader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());

    } catch (AmazonClientException exception) {
        logger.error("action", "awsError_failedToGetResponse",
                "class", exception.getClass()
                          .getSimpleName(),
                "errorMessage", exception.getMessage());
        throw exception;
    }
}
 private String getKey(String applicationId, S3FileDirectoryEnum directory) {
        return directory != null ? directory.getValue() + "/" + applicationId : applicationId;
    }
```

This is my method in service class. I want to mock `s3Client.getObject(getObjectRequest)` so that it can give me some data to assert. If anyone can help me on how to write test case for this method in Junit 5. It will be very helpful.

Comment: Since you already know what you want to test, what have you tried already? Moreover, your code is missing the surrounding class context, which is required to write a test since you need an object to call a method on.

Comment: everytime i try to mock the s3Client.getObject(), it returns me null pointer. How exactly should i mock it.  

ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse> s3ClientObject = mock(ResponseInputStream.class);

 when(s3ClientMock.getObject((GetObjectRequest) any())).thenReturn(s3ClientObject);

Comment: Show (all relevant parts of) your test class. Anything less is too little information.